# What is the the best way to modify (e.g., perform math functions) a column in a Dask DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I'm a veteran of Pandas DataFrame objects, but I'm struggling to find a clean, convenient method for altering the values in a Dask DataFrame column.  For a specific example, I'm trying to multiply positive values in a numpy.float column by -1, thereby making them negative.  Here is my current method (I'm trying to change the last column in the DataFrame):

```
cols = df.columns
df[[cols[-1]]] = df[[cols[-1]]]*-1
```

This seems to work only if the column has a string header, otherwise it adds another column using the index number as a string-type column name for a new column.  Is there something akin to the Pandas method of, say, `df.iloc[-1,:] = df.iloc[-1,:]*-1` that I can use with a Dask dataframe?

Edit: I'm also trying to implement: `df = df.applymap(lambda x: x*-1)`.  This, of course, applies the function to the entire dataframe, but is there a way to apply a function over just one column?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### first question

If something works for string columns and not for numeric-named columns then that is probably a bug.  I recommend raising an issue at https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new

#### second question

> but is there a way to apply a function over just one column?

You can't apply a single Python function over a dask dataframe that is stored in many pieces directly, however methods like `.map_partitions` or `.reduction` may help you to achieve the same result with some cleverness.

*in the future we recommend asking separate questions separately on stack overflow*

Comment: I didn't realize that I was asking two questions but this is noted and I apologize.

I haven't tried using .reduction yet and I'm beginning to look at .map_partitions... hopefully I'll have some success soon.  I'll mark this question as answered.  I greatly appreciate your response!  Thank you.